# lftp,stdout, stderr and SAP exec_protocol

Tags: bash, abap, lftp

We have linux scripts to do SFTP via preshared keys but recently a vendor is requiring the key and a password, I guess it is similar to two factor authentication.  So the vendor authenticates with the preshared key and then prompts for a password.  Until the password is entered, you are only partially authenticated.  So my standard scripts are not working.  To get around that, I discovered `lftp` can pass the password in a script and solves the problem of scripting putting and getting a file. Here is my script:

```
     #!/bin/sh
     # ###########################
     # Parameters
     # $1 Source Directory
     # $2 Source File
     # $3 Target IP
     # $4 Target File
     # $5 Target Directory
     # $6 Mode (binary or ascii)
     # $7 User
     # $8 Pwd
     # ###########################
         lftp sftp://$7:$8@$3 -e "cd $5; put $1$2; bye"
```

This script is called from an SAP abap program by calling the function `SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE`.  The return information from shell scripts are usually captured in the return parameter `EXEC_PROTOCOL`.  All works fine with all other bash scripts but with `lftp`, we are getting nothing in the from stdout.  We do get errors so I am assuming it is capturing stderr.  Any idea why this is?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.  Yes, I looked at this and you are right about the buffering.  I am now writing the output to a logfile and cat'ing the file at the end of the script.  Now the output is being captured because I am doing a cat of the log file at the end.  I will keep experimenting.

Comment: If you do not mind I will post my comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with neither SAP nor ABAP. Look at the post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/139662/how-can-i-capture-output-from-lftp-output-not-written-to-stdout-or-stderr) on the [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

The command might be buffering its output, see the accepted answer there and try to unbuffer it.